# nextcloud sub path domain

Tags: apache, ubuntu, nextcloud

I installed nextcloud in the /var/www/html/nextcloud folder using the following tutorial:
https://websiteforstudents.com/install-nextcloud-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts-with-apache2-mariadb-php-7-1-and-lets-encrypt-ssl-tls/

Now every time I access my my-domain.com it redirects me to my-domain.com/nextcloud
How do I leave my-domain.com empty to be added to another website?
My server is ubuntu 17 running apache

Comment: Is it `ServerName my-domain.com` in `nextcloud.conf`? That is, you named it so yourself.

Comment: My ServerName it's like my-domain.com/nextcloud

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing your DocumentRoot to `/var/www/html` in the apache config should fix this issue. Let me know if it worked.

Comment: I made this change, now at mydomain.com it gives the following error:

Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact your server administrator if this error reappears multiple times, please include the technical details below in your report.

More details can be found in the server log.

Comment: Can you post your apache config?